# jQuery ajax reload body and execute scripts

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I reload the whole page or `<body>` only on resize event and execute all the scripts.

I'd prefer case to reload only body, I've got all the heavy plugins inside head and on the end of body I've got `functions.js` where I do all the work over the body.

I've tried:

```
var url = document.URL;
$('html').load(url);
```

But scripts was not executed on new DOM.

Comment: Why would you want to reload the page when the window is resized? That sounds very annoying behaviour to me.

Comment: Im using columnized content and need to reload body when height is changed. I need to reload content again and execute all the scripts making it looking ok again.

Comment: Possibly a responsive web project? This would be a very bad approach

Comment: what you suggest? Content after columnizing is tottaly changed, divided into parts, and there is also many scripts done on content itself, some animationes etc. The all layout is changed to non-columnized when mobile-resolution. What you suggest to make it work 'smoothly'?

Answer (score 0):

to be honest without losing the scope you could better create the holder. else  your ajax call will not be very usefull. do it like the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Ajax preview</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="siteHolder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and than use the jQuery plugin you are using to insert a new page into the div with the id `#siteHolder` so what will looks like:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "example.html",
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(data) {
  $("#siteHolder").html( data );
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

this way you will only initiate your css and js library's once and keep more control over your document.

Answer (score 0):

To reload a page on window resize you can do this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  window.location.reload();
};
```

But I think what you really need is to create a responsive page. A responsive page will adjusts itself by the window size, if you resize the window, it will automatically adjust elements without reloading the page.

CSS Example:

```
/* Example for Smartphones */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Your Styles */
}

/* Example for  Desktops and laptops */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Your Styles */
}
```

Full example [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

I recommend you to search for Media queries and responsive design and you will find a lot of examples.